# How to programmatically create and present a new editor window in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, plugins

I'm working on a plugin for Xcode.

How do I programmatically show a new editor window containing an `IDEEditorArea`?

I'm targeting Swift or Objective-c.